# How to install Plone?

Tags: python, software-installation

I'm trying to install [Plone](http://plone.org/products/plone/releases/4.3.2). The installer says:

```
$ sudo ./install.sh 

Usage: [sudo] install.sh [options] standalone|zeo

Install methods available:
   standalone - install standalone zope instance
   zeo        - install zeo cluster

Use sudo (or run as root) for server-mode install.

Options (see top of install.sh for complete list):

--with-python=/full/path/to/python-2.7
  Path to the Python-2.7 that you wish to use with Plone.
  virtualenv will be used to isolate the install.

--build-python
  If you do not have a suitable Python available, the installer will
  build one for you if you set this option. Requires Internet access
  to download Python source.

--password=InstancePassword
  If not specified, a random password will be generated.

--target=pathname
  Use to specify top-level path for installs. Plone instances
  and Python will be built inside this directory
  (default is /usr/local/Plone)

--clients=client-count
  Use with the zeo install method to specify the number of Zope
  clients you wish to create. Default is 2.

--instance=instance-name
  Use to specify the name of the operating instance to be created.
  This will be created inside the target directory.
  Default is 'zinstance' for standalone, 'zeocluster' for ZEO.

--daemon-user=user-name
  In a server-mode install, sets the effective user for running the
  instance. Default is 'plone_daemon'. Ignored for non-server-mode installs.

--owner=owner-name
  In a server-mode install, sets the overall owner of the installation.
  Default is 'buildout_user'. This is the user id that should be employed
  to run buildout or make src or product changes.
  Ignored for non-server-mode installs.

--group=group-name
  In a server-mode install, sets the effective group for the daemon and
  buildout users. Default is 'plone_group'.
  Ignored for non-server-mode installs.

--template=template-name
  Specifies the buildout.cfg template filename. The template file must
  be in the buildout_templates subdirectory. Defaults to buildout.cfg.

--static-lxml
  Forces a static built of libxml2 and libxslt dependencies. Requires
  Internet access to download components.

Read the top of install.sh for more install options.
```

But I already have `ibxml2-dev` and `libxslt-dev` installed, so how to install Plone on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Usage: [sudo] install.sh [options] standalone|zeo
```

You need to specify `standalone` or `zeo`.

Comment: I won't accept your answer..... that's because SE doesn't let me accept your answer before 2 min :)